# Get parts of strings between two "\n"

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a JSON tag as a string, which has multiple end line characters(\n).
I need a regular expression which can match all the strings between them

```
String tag = "{ 

"key" = "value1"
"keyInd" = 2
"keyStopVal" = "(903, 3434 ,3434)"

}"
```

Expected Result = "key" = "value1", "keyInd" = 2, "keyStopVal" = "(903, 3434 ,3434)"

regex used right now :

```
(\\n[\\s\\-\\w]+)?=([\\s\\w\\-\\.\\,\\$\\{\\[\\]\"]+)\\n
```

Comment: why are you trying to parse JSON with a regex?

Comment: Actually you''ve a syntax error. Please show what you really have. Or is this a JavaScript question at all?

Comment: also, your question is not complete : javascript does not have strongly typed variables, so `String anything = ` isn't going to work. what language is this?

Comment: That's not [Json](http://json.org/). Json uses colons to separate key-value pairs, and places commas between each pair. If this is *supposed* to be Json, I'd recommend fixing the syntax and then using `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
/^[^=]+=[^\n]+$/gm
```

```js
let str = `{ 

"key" = "value1"
"keyInd" = 2
"keyStopVal" = "(903, 3434 ,3434)"

}`

let op = str.match(/"[^=]+=[^\n]+$/gm)

console.log(op)
```

**On Side note:** If the posted data is supposed to be valid JSON than you don't need regex at all

Comment: Your result returns an `{` as part of the first item.

Comment: Thanks @Code Maniac... after some tweaking...this regex helped me get there.

Answer (score 0):

This regex works on your provided string:

```
/".+"(.+)?=(.+)?"?.+"?\n/g
```

```js
var tag = `{ 

"key"="value1"
"keyInd" = 2
"keyStopVal" = "(903, 3434 ,3434)"

}`

let results = tag.match(/".+"(.+)?=(.+)?"?.+"?\n/g)

console.log(results)
```

Comment: You were fast! it should be noted though, that this is *javascript*, which OP isn't using.